# Dúvida Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Quantas listas suspensas o apache poi/excel 2016 suporta ?

Pergunto isso, pois estou trabalhando com um código que gera dinamicamente uma planilha com diversas listas dinâmicas, que dependendo da quantidade de dados que são selecionados para serem exportados o excel não consegue abrir a planilha.

Erro:

```
Excel found unreadable content in "abc.xlxs" .Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?If you trust the source of this workbook, click 'yes'
```

Versão do apache POI:

- poi-3.14-20160307.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14-20160307.jar
- poi-scratchpad-3.14-20160307.jar

OBS: O leitor WPS consegue abrir normalmente a planilha gerada, porém, o excel não. Já atualizei a lib para a última versão e mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!
Agradeço desde já!

Comment: O que seria uma lista suspensa (ou dinâmica)? Não entendi bem o problema.

Comment: @Dherik, ao gerar uma planilha com muitas listas suspensas o excel não está conseguindo abrir a planilha. Dê uma olhada nesse link sobre as listas suspensas / Data validation / DropDown: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataValidation.html

Comment: Está usando estas listas suspensas dentro de alguma tabela com células mescladas? Outra pergunta, de quantas listas suspensas estamos falando?